# wrong output in c for simple programs

Tags: c

Im a novice programmer. There's a recurring error while executing the programs.
The output displayed is either wrong or weird.
example for this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int age;

    age=969;

    printf("Methuselah was %d years old\n");

    return(0);
}
```

The output i'm getting is 4199232

How do I fix this? 
I use Quincy 2005

Comment: `printf("Methuselah was %d years old\n", age);`

Comment: #include <stdio.h> (the output error is not related to this but it's a mistake anyway)

Comment: Your compiler should be spitting out reams of warnings at you. Always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` at minimum) and ***never, ever*** accept code that compiles with any warnings (e.g. fix them and recompile until no warnings are issued) If you want to tighten things up even more, add `-pedantic` to increase the warning level even further. If you learn to write C with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` as part of your normal compile string, you will learn much quicker and be that much a better programmer for it.

Comment: What do you think is connecting that `%d` to the variable `age`?

Comment: @LucasSampaio: Oh, I see — yup, BLUEPIXY fixed up the empty `#include` line amongst other changes.  I didn't check the edit history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell `printf` which variable to print. To do this, pass `age` as an argument to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int age;
    age = 969;
    printf("Methuselah was %d years old\n", age);
    return 0;
}
```

Calling `printf("%d")` without specifying an argument causes a random value on the stack to be printed, giving weird outputs.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify what the variable corresponding to the `%d` in your format string is.
That line should probably be

```
printf("Methuselah was %d years old\n", age);
```